# Find which colors appears the most in an image

Tags: algorithm, image-processing

I have an image which I need to find the 2 range of colors which appears the most and color each one of them.

I need to find a line in my image. The problem is that the color of the line and the background can be any color, and I won't be able to change the settings of the color each time.

Is there any simple known algorithm to solve my problem? I know I'm not the 1st person to face this problem...

Thank you!

Comment: To find the most used colors, simply create a  [color histogram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_histogram) and look for the biggest values

Comment: If the background is uniform color histogram is good idea. first highest peak is the background and second will be foreground(if foreground is sharp has large area).

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved in different ways regard to the input image (assuming the images are noise free - only two colors) :

- gray scale image where pixels vary from 0 to 255: In this case create a histogram (image histogram calculate the occurrence of the colors in the image, for example a black image with a small white disk will have a histogram of two bars). From this histogram choose the the highest value as the color of the background and the other value for the line.
- Color image: In this case, you need to separate color channel from other channels, HSB (Hue Saturation Brightness) model is sufficient in many cases. Create a histogram of the H value and do the same as the in the grayscale case.

Thank you.